# invalid signature when attempting a sell

Tags: coinbase-api

I'm try to sell my bitcoin through the API from a specific wallet.

I have the GET calls working correctly, but the POST call is showing "invalid signature"

```
$API_KEY        = '*****';
$API_SECRET = '*****';

$data['amount'] = 10;
$data['currency']   = 'USD';
$data['quote']      = true;

$api_url    = '/v2/accounts/593b0285-****-****-****-f0ddcb6c9ccc/sells';
$timestamp  = time();
$signature  = hash_hmac('SHA256',$timestamp.'POST'.$api_url.json_encode($data),$API_SECRET;
$version    = '2017-11-11';
$headers    = array('CB-ACCESS-SIGN: '.$signature,
                   'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP: '.$timestamp,
                   'CB-ACCESS-KEY: '.$API_KEY,
                   'CB-VERSION: '.$version);

$ch     = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.coinbase.com'.$api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
$data   = curl_exec($ch);
```

This is the result I get from Coinbase

```
stdClass Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => authentication_error
                    [message] => invalid signature
                )
        )
)
```

I've changed the currency to BTC to try that.
The account id in the $api_url is the one from when I perform an account API call.

```
[id] => 593b0285-****-****-****-f0ddcb6c9ccc
[name] => BTC Wallet
[primary] => 1
[type] => wallet
```

Comment: is there more to your error message?

Comment: No, there's no headers sent, just that error which Coinbase send.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was missing the **Content-Type** from my header.

```
$headers    = array('CB-ACCESS-SIGN: '.$signature,
                    'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP: '.$timestamp,
                    'CB-ACCESS-KEY: '.$API_KEY,
                    'CB-VERSION: '.$version,
                    "Content-Type: application/json");
```

It all works correctly now